# Django ManyToManyField: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Tags: django, django-models

So you realize that the foreign key you have in your model should really be a m2m and you've adopted the practice to provide models.CASCADE as positional argument to a Foreign Key.
So you end up with this code:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, models.CASCADE)
```

You "fix" a few other things and suddenly end up with this tail of a backtrace with everything you try to do:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 157, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 316, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1516, in contribute_to_class
    elif self.remote_field.is_hidden():
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/reverse_related.py", line 144, in is_hidden
    return bool(self.related_name) and self.related_name[-1] == '+'
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

What's going on?

Comment: It might be time to adopt the practice of declaring `on_delete` as a keyword arg

Comment: @Sayse is right. I'm adopting this practice from now on as I just burnt an hour on this issue.

Answer (score 12):

The method signature for ManyToManyField and ForeignKey are not identical. The ManyToManyField 2nd positional argument is in fact 'related_name', which means you ended up passing models.CASCADE to the related_name as can be seen in the debugger:

```
> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py(1513)contribute_to_class()
-> if self.remote_field.symmetrical and (
(Pdb) p self.remote_field.related_name
<function CASCADE at 0x80645b400>
```

Now put a post-it on your monitor, cause in 3 months you'll do it again.

Comment: AAAARGH!! Definitely stick this on a post-it. I write heaps of these, yet I still just wasted an hour with this error, trawling through django code trying to understand how a callable was being passed as a related name. Alternatively, **always use kwarg for on_delete rather than positional**